# Scan all workspace on startup with null ls and eslint_d

Tags: eslint, neovim

Currently when I open a folder in neovim and open a file only the diagnostics from this file are available.

How can I have diagnostics load for all of the folder files when I open a folder?

I have the recommended set up for eslint_d and null-ls